# Unable to retrieve intent's extras

Tags: android

I have an activity that I use in multiples modes, so I have to do things like this:

```
    Intent i = new Intent(MainListActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
    extras.putInt("id", c.getId());
    extras.putInt("mode", AREA_MODE);
    i.putExtra("extras", extras);
    startActivity(i);
```

and in the `onCreate`:

```
    Intent i = this.getIntent();
    extras = i.getBundleExtra("extras");
    if(extras!=null){
        id = extras.getInt("id", -1);
        mode = extras.getInt("mode", COUNTRY_MODE);
    }
```

But the intent extras are always null. Am I missing something? Is there any way to do this?

EDIT: For some reason, the `getIntent()` method returns the previous `Intent` which in my case has no extra (main intent). I'm trying to figure out why.

Comment: Let's double check some things.  Can you post the full `onCreate` method of `MainActivity` and the full method in `MainListActivity` that creates this intent.  Also, since you're getting the previous intent, why don't you show the `onCreate` of MainListActivity` too.

Comment: your c.getId() might not have been int really. I had similar issue with getId() which usually returned strings with alphabetic characters but on occassion it gave strings constisting of digits only. In this case Android's putExtra (String, String) made a funny conversion so that when I tried to retrieve it with getString I got null, however I  could retrieve them with getInt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find the cause of this issue so i gave up on using one activity. I have create others activities extending the problematic one and it started working (with both approach). Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 4):

Aha! I just debugged this problem. It turns out to be *due to a subtle detail [documented in PendingIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html).*

- A PendingIntent is a reference to a system-maintained token. So even if the sending process restarts, *reconstructing a similar intent will retrieve the original PendingIntent.* Then the sender can cancel or change it.
- *Similar intent* == same operation, action, data, categories, components, and flags. Extras don't count!
- Intents that differ only in their Extras all retrieve the same token.

> A common mistake people make is to create multiple PendingIntent objects with Intents that only vary in their "extra" contents, expecting to get a different PendingIntent each time. This does *not* happen.

**Fix 1:** Make a *distinct* PendingIntent. It must have different operation, action, data, categories, components, or flags -- or request code integers.

**Fix 2:** Use `FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT` or `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` to *cancel or modify* any existing PendingIntent.

Those two fixes produce slightly different results. Either way, your new Extras should get through.

Answer (score 3):

Try like this:

In one Activity:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt("id", c.getId());
bundle.putInt("mode", AREA_MODE);    
i.putExtras(bundle);
```

In Another Activity:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    id = extras.getInt("id", -1);
    mode = extras.getInt("mode", COUNTRY_MODE);    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be this.

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainListActivity.this ,MainActivity.class);
i.putExtra("id", c.getId());
i.putExtra("mode", AREA_MODE);
startActivity(i);
```

and

```
Intent i = this.getIntent();
id = i.getIntExtra("id", -1);
mode = i.getIntExtra("mode", COUNTRY_MODE);
```

Comment: He's starting a `MainActivity` from a `MainListActivity`. He probably needs `MainListActivity.this` instead of `this` (which your code changed) because he's in an inner class.

Answer (score 0):

You **do not** add extras to an intent this way:

```
 i.putExtra("extras", extras);
```

This puts an extra called "extras" into the intent.  Your "extras" are in a non-standard place in the intent.  If your `onCreate()` code were to retrieve the object mapped to "extras" and look in it, you would find your "extras".

The standard way is to populate a [bundle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html) and add it to the intent via [putExtras](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtras%28android.os.Bundle%29):

```
i.putExtras(bundle);
```

or use the convenience methods like [putExtra](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20double%5B%5D%29):

```
i.putExtra("mode", AREA_MODE);
```

Comment: well, using "extras" isn't the recommended approach anyway.  What happened if you use the standard approach?

Comment: Still the same. The previous intent is returned.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly refer to the following link:

- http://thedevelopersinfo.com/2009/10/15/passing-data-between-activities-in-android/

Comment: Still not working. The getIntent() seems to return the previous intent which in my case has no extras.